# Is there a MATLAB function to convert symbolic expressions to MATLAB code indexing?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Example:  I have an array like this R = sym('R',[4 4]).  I do some symbolic operations and get an expression, which is a function of stuff like R1_2, R2_2, etc.  I'd like to paste the expression into some code, but I really want it to look like R(1,2), R(2,2) etc.  Is there a function to do this, or do I need to manually find/replace 16 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute your variable R with a unknown function R:

```
R = sym('R',[3 3]);
M=det(R)
funR = symfun(sym('R(x, y)'),[sym('x'),sym('y')]);
for rndx=1:size(R,1)
    for cndx=1:size(R,2)
        M=subs(M,R(rndx,cndx),funR(rndx,cndx));
    end   
end
```

Output:

`R(1, 1)*R(2, 2)*R(3, 3) - R(1, 1)*R(2, 3)*R(3, 2) - R(1, 2)*R(2, 1)*R(3, 3) + R(1, 2)*R(3, 1)*R(2, 3) + R(2, 1)*R(1, 3)*R(3, 2) - R(1, 3)*R(2, 2)*R(3, 1)`

vectorized version of the code above (faster):

```
[rndx,cndx]=ind2sub(size(R),1:numel(R));
M2=subs(M,num2cell(R(:))',num2cell(funR(rndx,cndx)))
```

Comment: Nice and simple, but for bigger inputs (e.g., 7-by-7 determinants) calling `subs` repeatedly is *very* inefficient. You could probably easily re-write this build up two cell arrays and call `subs` just once at the end. The result would probably be faster than using regular expressions.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion, for 7x7 the cell version is 10 times faster than my loop version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **regular expressions** for that.

As an example I'm using the determinant function, and I'm defining `R` of size 3x3 to save space. But the code is generic.

```
R = sym('R',[3 3]); %// example matrix
f = det(R); %// example function
str = char(f); %// convert to string
[split, match] = regexp(str, '\d+_\d+','split','match'); %// split string according
    %// to pattern "digits underscore digits"
match2 = cellfun(@ (x) ['(' regexprep(x, '_', ',') ')'] , match, 'uniformoutput', 0);
    %// replace `_` by `,` and include parentheses
match2{end+1} = ''; %// equalize number of cells, for concatenation
result = [split; match2]; %// concatenate cells
result = [result{:}]; %// concatenage strings
```

In this example, the symbolic function `f`

```
f =
R1_1*R2_2*R3_3 - R1_1*R2_3*R3_2 - R1_2*R2_1*R3_3 + R1_2*R2_3*R3_1 + R1_3*R2_1*R3_2 - R1_3*R2_2*R3_1
```

gives the following string as result:

```
result =
R(1,1)*R(2,2)*R(3,3) - R(1,1)*R(2,3)*R(3,2) - R(1,2)*R(2,1)*R(3,3) + R(1,2)*R(2,3)*R(3,1) + R(1,3)*R(2,1)*R(3,2) - R(1,3)*R(2,2)*R(3,1)
```